# Communication between nodejs express server and docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, express, networking

I'm building a system where users can connect to a server, whose sole responsibility is authentification. The main application sits in a docker container that is running a VNC server. https://github.com/wwwshwww/novnc-ros-desktop

Upon authentification I would like to direct the user towards the VNC view, but regular redirects would not work since the client would not know how to reach the container over WAN.

How can I pipe the VNC output through my main server back towards the client? Do I simply make a request to the VNC server and then pipe the response back towards the client or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any other suggestions for how to implement this system most efficiently will be much appreciated (since any latency increases need to be eliminated where possible).

[image: Overview]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to setup a TCP redirect with `ìptables` - exposing the internal :6080 port to the external IP address.

Or you can do it in your `Express` app - you establish a connection to the VNC and another one to the user and then you pipe between them - but implementing this correctly with all the right error handling is not trivial.

If your main concern is security and protecting against a weak VNC sever, this is not trivial either. You should look for a dedicated VNC proxy software that includes protocol validity enforcement.